# cannot backup my iphone 12 mini... "Could not back up the iPhone because the iPhone disconnected."

Tags: iphone

I have been trying to backup my iPhone for the last several hours.  It keeps saying: "Could not back up the iPhone because the iPhone disconnected."

Clearly my iPhone is not disconnected, it's still mounted and showing in the finder as well as the "Music" app.

I have rebooted the phone and my computer several times..........  What can I do to solve this nonsense?

Comment: Try a different cable. You might have a cable with an intermittent fault where it disconnects momentarily.